# Issue with returning the sum of array elements in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections

I have a 3d array in Java which is like this: (size 3x2x4)

```
{{{1,2,3,0},{1,2,0,3}},{{1, 1, 1, 0}, {1 , 1, 0, 1} } , {{ 2,2,2,0},{2,2,0,2}}};
```

I want to return the sum of every third and forth columns values, and to return as array the value of third and fourth columns. This means: (array value of third and fourth columns ; sum ), i.e right side is the sum of the array of third and fourth columns values.

```
{1,2,3,0} ---> [3 0] ; 3
{1,2,0,3} ---> [0 3] ; 3
{1,1,1,0} ---> [1 0] ; 1
{1,1,0,1} ---> [0 1] ; 1
{2,2,2,0} ---> [2 0] ; 2
{2,2,0,2} ---> [0 2] ; 2
```

I'm trying to implement this function in Java, I've implemented this:

```java
public static void sumElements(void)
{
    int[3][2][4] arr1 = {{{1,2,3,0},{1,2,0,3}},{{1, 1, 1, 0}, {1 , 1, 0, 1} } , {{ 2,2,2,0},{2,2,0,2}}};
    for (int i = 0 ;i < arr1.length ; l++)
    { 
        system.println.out( IntStream.of(arr1[i, 3 , i]).sum()); 
        system.println.out( IntStream.of(arr1[i, 3 , i]).sum()); // here I print the sum of third and fourth columns elements.
    }
}
```

Any help out how do I implement correctly that function? I came from world of C++ and I just started coding in Java for some months.

Comment: there are multiple typos in your example code

Comment: The code is a bit difficult to read, and could you explain a bit why do you choose 3-dimension array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this using streams.

- The `Arrays.stream`, streams the 2D arrays.
- The `flatMap`, then streams those into a stream of 1D arrays of length 4.
- Then you sum the `3rd` and `4th` values of each 1D array, and those sums are mapped to the stream.
- The values are returned in 3D array with each cell containing the 3rd and 4th values and then their sum.

```
int[][][] arr1 = { { { 1, 2, 3, 0 }, { 1, 2, 0, 3 } },
        { { 1, 1, 1, 0 }, { 1, 1, 0, 1 } },
        { { 2, 2, 2, 0 }, { 2, 2, 0, 2 } } };

int[][][] sum =
        Arrays.stream(arr1).flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                .map(a -> new int[][] { { a[2], a[3] },
                        { a[2] + a[3] } })
                .toArray(int[][][]::new);

for (int[][] a : sum) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
}
```

Prints

```
[[3, 0], [3]]
[[0, 3], [3]]
[[1, 0], [1]]
[[0, 1], [1]]
[[2, 0], [2]]
[[0, 2], [2]]
```

Here is a modification based on your comments.

- define array to subtract and lambda to perform the math.

```
int [] v = {1,0};   
Function<int[], int[][]> abs = a->{
        int c1 = (int)Math.abs(a[2]-v[0]);
        int c2 = (int)Math.abs(a[3]-v[1]);
        return new int[][] {{c1,c2},{c1+c2}};};
```

The streaming code to process the array and apply the lambda

```
int[][][] sum =
        Arrays.stream(arr1).flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                .map(abs::apply)
                .toArray(int[][][]::new);

for (int[][] a : sum) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
}
```

Prints

```
[[2, 0], [2]]
[[1, 3], [4]]
[[0, 0], [0]]
[[1, 1], [2]]
[[1, 0], [1]]
[[1, 2], [3]]
```

Comment: but I want to return the sum at each row, I mean by the row ..each four elements I want to return the sum of 3rd and fourth values as two elements in an array, and then I return their sum

Comment: What is the final value  you want?  12?  It isn't clear what  you want.

Comment: for example for { 1, 2, 3, 0 } to return as two elements in array {3,0} and their sum is 3. to do the same with every four elements(every row). this means to return two things one is array values of two elements of 3rd and fourth column of each row, second is to return their sum. you can do this by two functions/methods which one function returns the array of two elements , the other function returns its sum.

Comment: for example one function gives me the two elements of 3rd and fourth value of each row(row is the four elements group), this means for instance this:  { 1, 2, 3, 0 } returns  
{3, 0} , the other function returns its sum.

Comment: Is it okay to put those in a two D arrays like {{3,0}, {3}}?

Comment: yes exactly but because you already coded this , so my issue is now like this I wanted the last two elements for each row (row is the four elements in each group) to substract from it {1,1} (it's something constant) and then I do abs to the result and then I do the sum. For instance to be more clear: lets assume I have { 1, 2, 3, 0 } then I want to take the last two values (value of 3rd and fourth columns) {3,0} and to substract from them {1, 0 } so {3,0} - {1,0} gives me {3-1,0-0} = {2,0} and on this array I do abs because it might be negative and then I do the sum on result.

Comment: so the result for my example is sum(abs{2,0}) gives us sum({2,0}) = 2 so the result 2. the same thing for every row (for every group that consists of four elements)

Comment: for your question in the comment , for me it's good to return/print the result but inside a loop or something like this to do the same thing for every row (on every group), i.e to get the sum result for every group .

Comment: Ok. Check this out  If it isn't what you want perhaps you can use some of my attempts to solve your problem.  Good luck.

Comment: I understand exactly ! but Im confused because I want to substract from the two elements of 3rd and fourth columns the array {1,0} it means to get at the end:

Comment: [[3, 0] - [1 0] = [2 0], [2]]
[[0, 3] - [1 0] = [-1 3], [4]]
[[1, 0]-[1 0]=[0 , 0] , [0]]
[[0, 1]-[1 0]=[-1 1], [2]]
etc ... (I did implicitly abs to the result of the subtraction) and then I do the sum . could you please help me on this within your code?

Comment: exactly the same output as your code output, but before to print the output I need to subtract [1 0] from each array of the two elements and on the result I do abs and then I do sum

Comment: I updated your code comment with explanation, it would be much appreciated for any assistance because Im still confused how do I do the subtraction within your code ..

Comment: I updated your code and their I put comments in order to understand me what exactly my program print, I appreciate your assistance how do I do the subtraction for every two elements array..

Comment: Much appreciated , thanks alot.

Comment: I was struggling with my complete problem (
Relying on your code), I posted here the whole problem(thanks in advance for any assistance) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65602661/issue-with-my-implementation-function-in-java

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

**For the sum Method**

The code should be straightforward. So I go down all the three dimensions with the for loops and as you said the size is fixed.

> size 3x2x4)

In the last Dimension I just build the sum of the third and fourth element at index 2 and 3 and and then put it into a result array which I return afterwards.

```
public static int[] sumElements() {
    int[] sumArray = new int[6];
    int counter = 0;
    int[][][] arr1 = { { { 1, 2, 3, 0 }, { 1, 2, 0, 3 } }, { { 1, 1, 1, 0 }, { 1, 1, 0, 1 } },
            { { 2, 2, 2, 0 }, { 2, 2, 0, 2 } } };

    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr1[i].length; j++) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int l = 0; l < arr1[i][j].length; l++) {
                if (l == 2 || l == 3) {
                    sum += arr1[i][j][l];
                }
            }
            sumArray[counter] = sum;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return sumArray;
}
```

The output is `[3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2]`

**For the method which returns the two summands**
I create a temp array there I place the two values and then I push the array into a result array.

```
  public static int[][] sumands() {
        int secondCounter = 0;
        
        int[][] summandsArray = new int[6][2];
        int[][][] arr1 = { { { 1, 2, 3, 0 }, { 1, 2, 0, 3 } }, { { 1, 1, 1, 0 }, { 1, 1, 0, 1 } },
                { { 2, 2, 2, 0 }, { 2, 2, 0, 2 } } };

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            
            for (int j = 0; j < arr1[i].length; j++) {
            
                int firstCounter = 0;
                
                int[] tempArray = new int[2];
                for (int l = 0; l < arr1[i][j].length; l++) {
                    if (l == 2 || l == 3) {
                        

                        tempArray[firstCounter] = arr1[i][j][l];
                        firstCounter = firstCounter + 1;
                    }
                }
                summandsArray[secondCounter] = tempArray;
                secondCounter++;
            }
        }

        return summandsArray;
    }
}
```

The output is
`[[3, 0], [0, 3], [1, 0], [0, 1], [2, 0], [0, 2]]`

Now putting all together for a snippet which prints out the results.

```
package hall;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Whatever {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] sums = Whatever.sumElements();
        int[][] summands = Whatever.sumands();
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sums));
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(summands));
    }

    public static int[] sumElements() {
        int[] sumArray = new int[6];
        int counter = 0;
        int[][][] arr1 = { { { 1, 2, 3, 0 }, { 1, 2, 0, 3 } }, { { 1, 1, 1, 0 }, { 1, 1, 0, 1 } },
                { { 2, 2, 2, 0 }, { 2, 2, 0, 2 } } };

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr1[i].length; j++) {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int l = 0; l < arr1[i][j].length; l++) {
                    if (l == 2 || l == 3) {
                        sum += arr1[i][j][l];
                    }
                }
                sumArray[counter] = sum;
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return sumArray;
    }

    public static int[][] sumands() {
        int secondCounter = 0;
        
        int[][] summandsArray = new int[6][2];
        int[][][] arr1 = { { { 1, 2, 3, 0 }, { 1, 2, 0, 3 } }, { { 1, 1, 1, 0 }, { 1, 1, 0, 1 } },
                { { 2, 2, 2, 0 }, { 2, 2, 0, 2 } } };

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            
            for (int j = 0; j < arr1[i].length; j++) {
            
                int firstCounter = 0;
                
                int[] tempArray = new int[2];
                for (int l = 0; l < arr1[i][j].length; l++) {
                    if (l == 2 || l == 3) {
                        

                        tempArray[firstCounter] = arr1[i][j][l];
                        firstCounter = firstCounter + 1;
                    }
                }
                summandsArray[secondCounter] = tempArray;
                secondCounter++;
            }
        }

        return summandsArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will update your code to understand me and appreciated for any assistance in advance.

Comment: the better way would be when you update your question to clarify more what you actually want

Comment: thanks for your assistance ! but you still misunderstanding me , after we have the array value of two elements I want to substract from each array of the two elements the array value [1 0] and I get a new value which it's the reuslt of subtraction , then I do abs and then to do the sum

Comment: Again update your question put some input and expected output inside your question and clarify this.
You have to consider when someone else sees this question and maybe have a similar problem he will probably not read all this comments instead he will just take a look at the question and think about does it fit to my problem.

Comment: I understand but I can't edit it because I have no permission  for now!

Comment: ok well so when I have the summands for example [3, 4] then I subtract [1 0] this means I return [2, 4] and this I will do for every array in the summandsArray, is that what you mean? 
And actually you should be able to edit your own post ..

Comment: Next time I will take your note about my thread to improve the edition and to ask more specified. thanks for this tip

Comment: Well so you have solved your problem? And np :)

Comment: Yup, I'm trying to fix myself the other problem I've in my code, if didn't succeed I will post a thread in the incoming hours(it depends, first I will depend on myself) thanks.

Comment: I was struggling with my complete problem (
Relying on what I started on this thread), I posted here the whole problem(thanks in advance for any assistance) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65602661/issue-with-my-implementation-function-in-java

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reformat the code to look more readable, and a simple loop may do the job, you won't probably have to use IntStream unless you were asked to do so,

Here is my attempt :

```
 public static void sumElements() {
    int[][][] arr1 = {
            {
                    {1, 2, 3, 0},
                    {1, 2, 0, 3}
            },
            {
                    {1, 1, 1, 0},
                    {1, 1, 0, 1}
            },
            {
                    {2, 2, 2, 0},
                    {2, 2, 0, 2}
            }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) { // goes from 0 to 2
        for (int j = 0; j < arr1[i].length; j++) { // goes from 0 to 1
            System.out.println(arr1[i][j][2] + arr1[i][j][3]);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand, but I need to return the sum (as what you did in the print) and to return the two elements of 3rd and fourth element. it can be another function to return the two elements of the sum as array values at each iteration.

Comment: Then I think you have to reformulate your question

Comment: I was struggling with my complete problem (
Relying on your code), I posted here the whole problem(thanks in advance for any assistance) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65602661/issue-with-my-implementation-function-in-java

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the third dimension of the 3d array by the third and fourth columns:

```java
int[][][] arr3d = {
        {{1, 2, 3, 0}, {1, 2, 0, 3}},
        {{1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1}},
        {{2, 2, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 0, 2}}};

int[][] arr = Arrays.stream(arr3d)
        .map(arr2d -> Arrays.stream(arr2d)
                // sum of third and fourth columns
                .mapToInt(arr1d -> arr1d[2] + arr1d[3])
                .toArray())
        .toArray(int[][]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
// [[3, 3], [1, 1], [2, 2]]
```

Flatten 2d array to 1d array:

```java
int[] flatArr = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
        .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(flatArr));
// [3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```